# Why am I unable to extract text via Apache Tika using Lucee?

Tags: java, apache-tika, lucee

I would like to extract text from pdf, docx etc via Lucee 5+ (5.2.9), but unfortunately I get empty result set. I have used several [Apache Tika versions](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/tika/tika-app/) (runnable jar with Java 1.8.0) that might fit to my specific Lucee and Java requirements, but the result set always remains empty.

**exract.cfc**

```
component {
    
    public any function init() {

        _setTikaJarPath( GetDirectoryFromPath( GetCurrentTemplatePath( ) ) & "tika-app-1.19.1.jar" );

        return this;

    }


    private struct function doParse( required any fileContent, boolean includeMeta=true, boolean includeText=true ) {
        var result  = {};
        var is      = "";
        var jarPath = _getTikaJarPath();

        if ( IsBinary( arguments.fileContent ) ) {
            is = CreateObject( "java", "java.io.ByteArrayInputStream" ).init( arguments.fileContent );
        } else {
            // TODO, support plain string input (i.e. html)
            return {};
        }

        try {
            var parser = CreateObject( "java", "org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser", jarPath );
            var ch     = CreateObject( "java", "org.apache.tika.sax.BodyContentHandler" , jarPath ).init(-1);
            var md     = CreateObject( "java", "org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata"      , jarPath ).init();

            parser.parse( is, ch, md );

            if ( arguments.includeMeta ) {
                result.metadata = {};

                for( var key in md.names() ) {
                    var mdval = md.get( key );
                    if ( !isNull( mdval ) ) {
                        result.metadata[ key ] = _removeNonUnicodeChars( mdval );
                    }
                }
            }

            if ( arguments.includeText ) {
                result.text = _removeNonUnicodeChars( ch.toString() );
            }

        } catch( any e ) {
            result = { error = e };
        }

        return result;
}


    public function read(required string filename) {
        var result = {};

        if(!fileExists(filename)) {
            result.error = "#filename# does not exist.";
            return result;
        };

        var f = createObject("java", "java.io.File").init(filename);
        var fis = createObject("java","java.io.FileInputStream").init(f);

        try {
            result = doParse(fis);
        } catch(any e) {
            result.error = e;
        }
        fis.close();
        return result;
    }

    private string function _removeNonUnicodeChars( required string potentiallyDirtyString ) {
        return ReReplace( arguments.potentiallyDirtyString, "[^\x20-\x7E]", "", "all" );
    }

// GETTERS AND SETTERS
    private string function _getTikaJarPath() {
        return _tikaJarPath;
    }
    private void function _setTikaJarPath( required string tikaJarPath ) {
        _tikaJarPath = arguments.tikaJarPath;
}


}
```

and the code that i use to run it

```
<cfset takis = new exract()>
<cfset files = directoryList(expandPath("./sources"))>
<cfloop index="f" array="#files#">
    <cfif not findNoCase(".DS_Store",f)>
        <cfdump var="#takis.read(f)#" label="#f#">
    </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is a class clash: The Lucee core engine already loads a version of Tika meaning the one you point to is ignored. But the loaded version doesn't behave as expected, returning empty strings as you've seen.

I've solved this by using OSGi to load the desired Tika version. This involves editing the Manifest of the tika-app jar to include basic OSGi metadata and then loading it via my [osgiLoader](https://github.com/cfsimplicity/luceeOsgiLoader)

There is a pre-built [Tika bundle](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tika/tika-bundle) available but I haven't been able to get it to work with Lucee.

Here's how to convert the latest `tika-app` jar to OSGi:

1. open the "tika-app-1.28.2.jar" with 7-zip
2. open META-INF then select MANIFEST.MF and press F4 to open it in a text editor
3. add the following to the end of the file:

```
Bundle-Name: Apache Tika App Bundle
Bundle-SymbolicName: apache-tika-app-bundle
Bundle-Description: Apache Tika App jar converted to an OSGi bundle
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Version: 1.28.2
Bundle-ClassPath: .,tika-app-1.28.2.jar
```

4. Save choosing to update when prompted.

You can then call the jar using osgiLoader as follows:

**extractor.cfc**

```
component{

    property name="loader" type="object";
    property name="tikaBundle" type="struct";

    public extractor function init( required object loader, required struct tikaBundle ){
        variables.loader = arguments.loader
        variables.tikaBundle = arguments.tikaBundle
        return this
    }

    public string function parseToString( required string filePath ){
        try{
            var fileStream = CreateObject( "java", "java.io.FileInputStream" ).init( JavaCast( "string", arguments.filePath ) )
            var tikaObject = loader.loadClass( "org.apache.tika.Tika", tikaBundle.path, tikaBundle.name, tikaBundle.version )
            var result = tikaObject.parseToString( fileStream )
        }
        finally{
            fileStream.close()
        }
        return result
    }

}
```

(The following script assumes `extractor.cfc`, the modified Tika jar, the [`osgiLoader.cfc`](https://github.com/cfsimplicity/luceeOsgiLoader/blob/main/osgiLoader.cfc) and the document to be processed are in the same directory.)

**index.cfm**

```
<cfscript>
docPath = ExpandPath( "test.pdf" )
loader = New osgiLoader()
tikaBundle = {
    version: "1.28.2"
    ,name: "apache-tika-app-bundle"
    ,path: ExpandPath( "tika-app-1.28.2.jar" )
}
extractor = New extractor( loader, tikaBundle )
result = extractor.parseToString( docPath )
dump( result )
</cfscript>
```

Another way to get the right version loaded is to use [JavaLoader](https://github.com/markmandel/JavaLoader). For some reason I couldn't get it to work with the latest `tika-app` jar (`1.28.2`), but `1.19.1` does seem to work.

### Hacking the existing extension

I would advise you to raise an issue with Preside to change their extension to avoid the clash, but as a temporary hack you could try amending it yourself as follows:

First, add your modified Tika bundle and the `osgiLoader.cfc` to the `/preside-ext-tika/services/` directory.

Next, change line 14 of `DocumentMetadataService.cfc` so the name of the Tika jar path matches your modified bundle.

```
_setTikaJarPath( GetDirectoryFromPath( GetCurrentTemplatePath( ) ) & "tika-app-1.28.2.jar" );
```

Then, modify lines 33-35 of the same cfc to replace:

```
var parser = CreateObject( "java", "org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser", jarPath );
var ch     = CreateObject( "java", "org.apache.tika.sax.BodyContentHandler" , jarPath ).init(-1);
var md     = CreateObject( "java", "org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata"      , jarPath ).init();
```

with the following:

```
var loader = New osgiLoader();
var tikaBundle = { version: "1.28.2", name: "apache-tika-app-bundle" };

var parser = loader.loadClass( "org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser", jarPath, tikaBundle.name, tikaBundle.version )
var ch     = loader.loadClass( "org.apache.tika.sax.BodyContentHandler" , jarPath, tikaBundle.name, tikaBundle.version ).init(-1)
var md     = loader.loadClass( "org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata"      , jarPath, tikaBundle.name, tikaBundle.version ).init()
```

NB: I don't have Preside so can't test it in context.

Comment: Hello! I have used the JavaLoader version (apache-tika-1.18.jar) and works without any problem for me but the problem is to embed it into the existing apache tika plugin without changing the code (https://github.com/pixl8/preside-ext-tika). Regarding OSGI bundles, i follow your instructions but nothing happens perhaps due to inexperience.I need a ready solution and i have found a repository, but i am not sure if it's compatible with lucee (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/tika/tika-bundle-standard/). As previously stated,i do not want to change the existing plugin code. Thanks a lot!

Comment: As I said, I couldn't get the pre-built tika-bundle (in the repo you found) to work in Lucee due to an osgi "wiring" error. Modifying the tika-app jar and loading it via osgiLoader as I described does work. The code is tested. Make sure all of the files are in the same directory: `extractor.cfc`, `index.cfm`, `osgiLoader.cfc`, and `tika-app-1.28.2.jar` (modified) and the doc you want to parse.

Comment: Could you mind take a look at this specific tika jar file  (manifest.ml something may be missing) as it can not get loaded via bundle-jar gui? (https://wetransfer.com/downloads/3fbf2577baec48ef7652fba11accc24e20220520075837/7b5f30). I just found another interesting article (https://dev.lucee.org/t/external-jar-file-problem-tika/6525/6).  Regards

Comment: The jar file is fine but it is version 1.28 whereas as the code I posted was for 1.28.2. If you change the `tikaBundle.version` and `tikaBundle.path` in the index.cfm script it should work (does for me with the your modified jar).

Comment: I've created a basic wrapper on Github which you should be able to use without having to do any of the OSGi preparation and loading yourself: https://github.com/cfsimplicity/lucee-tika

Comment: I used my own OSGI version and it runs OK and definitely your basic wrapper that you just prepared, no doubt.The problem that i have got is that i use an existing framework (PresideCMS) and not free CF code that takes specific requirements during file upload (https://github.com/pixl8/preside-ext-tika) such as filecontent via java.io.ByteArrayInputStream and not filename.If you could see carefully it's code and prepare a custom basic wrapper according to its requirements, it would free my hands. Now your solutions are OK for pure CF, but using PresideCMS i get error during file upload. Regards

Comment: I'm not familiar with Preside and would recommend you raise this issue with Dom who's the maintainer. But I've added a possible way of hacking the existing extension. Not tested as I don't use Preside.

Comment: I have already spoken  with Dom and it is up to me now as this specific extension is not in use any more. Please visit https://presidecms-slack.herokuapp.com/ for more information regarding this issue between me and Dom. I expect honestly your solution as it would help me a lot! Regards

Comment: I don't have access to the Preside Slack. Did you try the hack I added to my answer?

Comment: Sorry I just saw that you just updated your reply now! I will definitely try it and let you know by tomorrow if it's ok. Thank you a lot!!!

Comment: Hello!I think that something wrong is happening with this plugin as i use hard-coded value for result.text="blabla" and even delete everything except return result in _parse function and nothing is finally returned as DB result.Since no support is offered for this specific plugin, i do not know what to do.Regards

Comment: This is for getText() in https://github.com/pixl8/Preside-CMS/blob/stable/system/services/assetManager/DocumentMetadataService.cfc. It's mentioned via comments. Regards

Comment: Sorry, I can't help with Preside, I'm not familiar with it. Can't you just use my wrapper to extract text from your files after they've been uploaded via Preside?

Comment: That sounds good, but I do not know how to do it via preside framework. psys_asset is system object and not custom object that all information for each asset is stored. Regards

Comment: If I install lucee via commandbox (in this case presidecms), where I see my log files (exact log location) for cfdump output=console. I just need to debug (dump output=console) result variable of _parse function each time is called. If I dump result variable together with function name, it would help me a lot. Regards

Comment: For general support with Lucee/commandbox you're best heading over to http://cfml-slack.herokuapp.com/ or https://dev.lucee.org/